# Ayuda con filtro de fechas en django

Tags: django

Buen día

Tengo una duda sobre los filtros para fechas, yo tengo un modelo llamado Ausentismo que tiene un atributo "fecha_inicio" y uno "fecha_fin", y tengo problemas con el filtro de una consulta para crear unas gráficas.

Por ejemplo, tengo un registro de ausentismo con fecha_inicio = 1 junio 2016 y fecha_fin = 3 junio. Si hago una consulta del 1 al 3 de junio me sale el ausentismo y puedo contar los días, pero si hago la consulta del 1 al 2, me sale una lista vacía.

Me podrían por favor además de ayudarme, también aclararme sobre el uso de modificadores en el filter como fecha__lt, fecha__gt, fecha__lte, fecha__gte? hay otros? hay de rango?

## Mi models.py

```
class AusentismoBase(Novedad):
    fecha_inicio = models.DateField(verbose_name="Fecha Inicial")
    fecha_fin = models.DateField(verbose_name="Fecha Final")
    mes = models.IntegerField(validators=[no_negativo])
    quincena = models.IntegerField(validators=[no_negativo])
    hora_inicio = models.TimeField(verbose_name="Hora Inicial", blank=True, null=True)
    hora_fin = models.TimeField(verbose_name="Hora Final", blank=True, null=True)
    motivo = models.IntegerField(choices=MOTIVOS_AUSENTISMO, verbose_name="Motivo de Ausentismo")
    tipo_inc = models.IntegerField(choices=TIPOS_INCAPACIDAD, verbose_name="Tipo de Incapacidad", blank=True, null=True)
    eps = models.ForeignKey(Eps)
    arl = models.ForeignKey(Arl)
    edad = models.IntegerField(validators=[no_negativo])
    salario = models.IntegerField(validators=[no_negativo])

    def __unicode__(self):
        return (u"Ausentismo %s: (%s - %s)"%(self.persona, self.motivo, self.fecha_inicio)).strip() or "-"

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("persona", "fecha_inicio"),)
```

## Mi views.py

```
def ausentismo_motivos_area_fechas(request, idArea=None, fechai=None, fechaf=None):
    resultado = iniciarResultadoTupla(MOTIVOS_AUSENTISMO)
    ausentismos = []
    form = AreaFechasForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AreaFechasForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            area = form.cleaned_data['area']
            fechai = form.cleaned_data['fechai']
            fechaf = form.cleaned_data['fechaf']
            return redirect('ausentismo_motivos_area_fechas', area.id, fechai, fechaf)

    if idArea and fechai and fechaf:
        idArea = int(idArea)
        area = Area.objects.get(id=idArea)
        fechai = moddate.strptime(fechai, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        fechaf = moddate.strptime(fechaf, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        ausentismos = AusentismoBase.objects.filter(area=area, fecha_inicio__gte=fechai, fecha_fin__lte=fechaf)
        print(ausentismos)
        for a in ausentismos:
            i = a.motivo - 1
            x = a.fecha_inicio.day
            y = a.fecha_fin.day
            for m in range(x, y+1):
                resultado[i] = llenarDatos(resultado[i], a.persona)

    form = AreaFechasForm(initial={'area':idArea, 'fechai':fechai, 'fechaf':fechaf})
    fila_0 = ['Motivo de Ausencia', 'B', 'C']
    graficas = [6, 4, 5]

    return render(request, 'plantilla_tipoempl.html', {
        'nombreGrafica': "Ausentismos Motivos Areas",
        'ejey': "Núm. Ausentismos",
        'ejex': "Motivos de Ausentismos",
        'resultadoJSON': json.dumps(resultado),
        'tipoEstadistica': "Ausentismos", #Clasificación de Estadísticas
        'resultado': resultado,
        'graficas': graficas,

        'fila_0': fila_0,
        'form': form,
        'filtro': "rango de fechas", #Sub Clasificación
        'ausentismos': ausentismos,
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer filtros con rangos de fechas u otras costas, siempre utilizo

```
obj = models.filter(start_stamp__range=[inicio, fin])
```